# How to restrict cart discount for specific (logged in) customer in magento 2?

Tags: magento

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICckJ.png)

i want to restrict cart discount for specific (logged in) customer.
so how it is possible in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4439065/4417447

Yes you can restrict discount for group of users. So give this link a try.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but i want to restrict specific customer , how it is possible to restrict specific customer? (like if i have 10 customer of general group then i just want to apply sales rule for only 4 customer rest of 6 customer will not have benefit).